# No drives to choose while formatting

Tags: windows, hard-drive, formatting, hardware-failure

I was trying to format my friend's computer and when we came to the point where we have to choose which drive to install windows on, there was no option to choose from, i.e there were no drives listed.

What does this imply? Has the hard disk crashed?

edit:  I had windows 7 installed, I am trying to install windows 7 again, and ya i get the option of only startable portions etc etc, but the thing is its not showing even a single optiona t all, be it eligible to put windows 7 in it or not, there is no god damn option there, so my q is , why is this so?

Comment: 1. Does the Computer have an Operating System Running?
2. Which file system is the Disk formatted with?
3. Which tool are you using to format the computer?
4. Which Operating System will you load after formatting?

Comment: What version of Windows are you installing?

Comment: Have you verified the drive is connected properly and has power? Is the drive recognized by the BIOS?

Comment: Do you need drivers for a raid controller that the drive is attached to?

Comment: try the q now gyus

Comment: What is the manufacturer and model of computer, or is it custom built?

Comment: dell r14 it is.

Answer (score 0):

depending on how you formatted the drive, you may have missed setting one of the partitions as "startable".  you can only install to 'startable' partitions.

Comment: added info tot he q, you might want to have a look